# Wordpress private images

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I want to have a page that is only visible to logged on users to show an image. I don't have a problem creating the page and showing the content but I want to store the image in a location accessible by php but that site scrapers will not be able to find, ie is only accessible from the server. Is there a folder that is invisible to the outside world that I can store the image in?

Thanks

Comment: You want to have a server-side check that serves the image file only to logged in users (or something like that).

Comment: Thats fine, but if the image is stored in the media library I'm concerned that those images are available for scammers to access with website scraping/download tools.